# Is there a module to convert a py file to apk?

Tags: python, android, type-conversion, apk, converters

I am looking for a python module that converts py files to apk. I've looked some questions about it in here. But could not find a proper answer. I am using windows 10. Python 3.9.0.
Thanks...

Comment: maybe using this framework would allow you to write python code/module to an android apps (buildable to apk): https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

There is not module that converts py files to an apk, but if you want to do android in python you can use frameworks like [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home).

Comment: I have to re-make the program in kivy. Is there another way?

Comment: It's a poem generator.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific. I mean what is it's format. Is it just some python files? Does it have a UI? Are you using any libraries?

Comment: It's just some python files. Imported each other. I used only random module. No libraries

Comment: In that case you shouldn't have to  re-make your the program in kivy. You should just be able to take your code and use kivy to add a UI to it.  Kivy is a "Python library for rapid development of applications that make use of innovative user interfaces" or in english a layer between your python code and the android system. Note: python was not made for mobile and isn't used much for it either so you don't really have a lot of choices.